# Adicionar inputs dinamicamente VueJs/Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, input

estou aprendendo a trabalhar com vue.js, e preciso de algo relativamente simples mas que não consegui resolver, gerar inputs dinamicamente em um formulario. Basicamente o formulario já vem com um input, e sempre que clicar no botão adicionar tem que adicionar mais um input, podem me ajudar?

```js
<template>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <div class="name">
            <h5><b>Nome da Seção: </b></h5>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Digite aqui o nome da seção">
        </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="idDiv">   
        <h5>Digite os Itens:</h5>     
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item" placeholder="Digite o nome do Item" style="max-width:300px;">        
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="submit">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" style="min-width:150px;">Adicionar</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" style="min-width:150px;">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
    export default {

}
</script>
```

Comment: Luiz talvez algo assim? https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-river-0o18k?file=/src/App.vue Dá uma olhada nessa parte da documentaçāo: https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: isso mesmo muito obrigado

Comment: @JoséEduardoKimura poderias copiar esse código para a resposta (e com o link)? somente o link é pouco para resposta, mas a tua solução é boa e daria uma boa respoata para eu dar `+1` ;)

Answer (score 2):

o seguinte, vamos criar um novo método `data` que retorna objetos dentro do componente atual, dentro de `data` criaremos um 'contador', no exemplo dei o nome de input mesmo, input vai começar com o valor 1.

```
export default {
  data: () => {
      return {
        input: 1
       }
  }
}
```

Na parte do botão 'Adicionar' vamos definir um manipulador de eventos que vai interagir com o contador 'input' definido anteriormente. Funciona assim, a cada clique no botão vai ser adicionado ao contador 'input' mais uma unidade.

```
<button @click="input++" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" style="min-width:150px;">Adicionar</button>
```

No Input vamos utilizar o `v-for` para renderizar no html a quantidade de inputs baseado no contator 'input' que definimos anteriormente.

```
<input v-for="i in input" :key="i" type="text" class="form-control" :id='"item"+i' :placeholder="'Digite o nome do Item '+i" style="max-width:300px; margin-top:5px">
```

Note que utilizei uma bind no `id` do input para gerar dinamicamente um novo id a cada novo input adicionado ao nosso contador, o id para cada input ficara assim `'item' + valor do contador`. Exemplo 'item1', 'item2', 'item3....
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode entender mais do `v-for` aqui
https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Manipuladores de eventos aqui
https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Dados e métodos aqui
https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Dados-e-Metodos